# How to set Notepad++ as TortoiseSVN default editor?

Tags: tortoisesvn, external, viewer

Sometimes I browse a repository and want to look at some files there, without checking them out (let's say I'm looking for a particular file). I've got three choices

- double clicking the file opens the default editor. For .cs files that would be the big and slow Visual Studio. And, naturally, it has to open a fresh copy.
- Right-clicking also offers the option to "Open With..." and then I can select what program I want
- Right clicking also offers the option to "Edit" which then opens Notepad.

I'd like to use Notepad++ as the default editor. Or it can be the "Edit" entry on the context menu that opens it, but not the full and lengthy "Open with..." dialog. Can I do that? I haven't yet found such a setting, but maybe there's some hidden option or something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like Mand Beckett said, and this is the full registry path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit\command
```

Change (Default) value in this key. Remember to leave %1 there.

The problem with solution above is that it will only handle files that are perceived as text (have value PerceivedType=text in registry). Most text files are already perceived as such in the registry, but you can't open, for instance, a .lib file in this manner. To be able to open really all files from repository browser with Notepad++ edit (Default) value in the following key (add the key if not there):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\edit\command
```

NOTE: In registry editor new key will have (Default) value of type REG_SZ, not REG_EXPAND_SZ. If you want REG_EXPAND_SZ you must create a key with .reg file.

Another option is to set all relevant file types to open from Notepad++ by default instead from Visual Studio. Start Notepad++ as administrator and in Settings > Preferences > File Association just add those file associations that you use.

Comment: Oh, so TortoiseSVN simply calls the default "Edit" command on the file? How... disappointing. :P Well, thanks for the detailed explanation! :)

Comment: Solution worked for me with many different file types - except .csv, which seems very weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Windows registry options to do that. You can change the default `open` program from within the Tortoise settings, but it is the `edit`
function you want. Look for

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations
```

in regedit.